# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

Tags: php, mysql

I'm receiving this error while I'm trying to connect to a database from a different server. I saw some solutions in some forums suggesting a change in the bind-address in my.cnf. But the problem is I have to connect the database from the same server as well.

So what can I do about this, so that I can connect the db from either servers?

Please tell me if I've to give more details.

Thanks

Comment: what is the server? linux? debian? etc?

Comment: this bug reminds me a problem with /etc/hosts.deny, but by default, it's not enable on debian, anything in this file except comments?

Comment: nope. just lots of commented statements.

Comment: iptable config maybe: iptables -L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've figured out the solution. The trick is to comment the bind address in my.cnf file.

Comment: It's worth adding, for anyone else getting this error:  Make sure you reboot MySQL after making this change, or connections will still fail.

Comment: FWIW, same problem while setting up multiple nodes in a xtradb cluster. Commented out this line in each node's config and restarted/readded each node to cluster and I could connect (through haproxy) as expected. Thanks.